# How can I see what packages were installed using `sudo pip install`?

Tags: python, pip, sudo

I know that installing python packages using `sudo pip install` is bad a security risk. Unfortunately, I found this out after installing quite a few packages using `sudo`.

Is there a way to find out what python packages I installed using `sudo pip install`? The end goal being uninstallment and correctly re-installing them within a virtual environment.

I tried `pip list` to get information about the packages, but it only gave me their version. `pip show <package name>` gave me more information about an individual package such as where it is installed, but I don't know how to make use of that information.

Comment: Well, my guess is, you did `sudo pip install` whenever you were installing site packages and not in a virtualenvironment. I'd start by getting rid of any site packages.

Comment: As @Ares suggested, I would just purge all packages in the list and reinstall them, `pip uninstall <package>`

Comment: Have you tried the `which` command?

Comment: @NerdOfCode I have not tried which. How would one use that command to achieve this? artomason and Ares I am sharing this machine with some other users, so I want to avoid just purging everything because it might purge some of their stuff.

Comment: Disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any modules you installed with `sudo` will be owned by root, so you can open your shell/terminal, `cd` to `site-packages` directory & check the directories owner with `ls -la`, then any that has `root` in the owner column is the one you want to uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `sudo pip install`, pip will install the package in your global site-packages directory.

So, to determine which packages you've installed with `sudo pip install`, you can navigate to your /site-packages directory.

The site-packages directory is a sub-directory of your python installation. For example, /Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122327/6131799) has a more detailed discussion regarding how to find the site-packages directory.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

try the following command: `pip freeze`

Comment: The question is about distinguishing `sudo pip install` from `pip install`. How does `pip freeze` help in distinguishing?