# Where is StarCluster Installed on MacOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, starcluster

I installed "StarCluster" using the terminal on my MacOs by following instructions from the link provided below. Now, I need to edit the configuration file to add my AWS credentials. However, I am not sure which folder "StarCluster" is installed on my hard drive. Does anyone know how to locate the folder ? I would appreciate your help.

http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [easy-install docs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#downloading-and-installing-a-package):

> By default, packages are installed to the running Python installation's site-packages directory, unless you provide the -d or --install-dir option to specify an alternative directory, or specify an alternate location using distutils configuration files.

Here's a guide to [finding your site-packages directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to locate the site-packages directory for starcluster. However, the only config file I was able to find there is "config.py" and it does not have the following part for me to enter my aws credentials: 

[aws info]

aws_access_key_id = #your aws access key id here

aws_secret_access_key = #your secret aws access key here

aws_user_id = #your 12-digit aws user id here

Comment: Did you run `starcluster help` to configure after install?

Comment: I did and choose the option to create a new config file, however, the only config file I see in the starcluster folder is "config.py" which is a python file. Am I suppose to change the aws credentials of this file ?

Comment: The config file won't be in the `site-packages` folder, it will be in the user's home directory. Try `cd ~/.starcluster` and see what you find. You can also put the config file anywhere you'd like using `starcluster -c /path/to/starcluster/config`

Comment: I am able to view the config file from the terminal using "starcluster -c /path/to/starcluster/config listclusters", however, I don't know how to edit it to enter my aws credentials. Is there a way to do this from the terminal ?

Comment: Yes, it depends on your system, but use an editor like nano or vim. Try `nano <path to your config>`, so if you've created the config file in your home dir, it would be `nano ~/config`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I used vim to open and edit the config file from the terminal.