# can't find rllib command after install ray

Tags: python, ray

I want try this command:

```
rllib train --env=Pong-ram-v4 --run=PPO
```

but **rllib** is can't find, I can do this by directly execute train.py in rllib source code, but run with a command is certainly more elegant. can some one tell me what's wrong?

here is the command I install ray:

```
pip install ray[rllib]
```

I try install it with/without virutual environment, both failed.

Comment: You said that `pip install ray[rllib]` failed. Can you share the error message?

Comment: the installation is sucessfull.  I can import ray and rllib in a python script, I just can't user rllib as a shell command.

Comment: Maybe you're using an old version of Ray? Try `pip install -U --force-reinstall ray` and make sure `python -c "import ray; print(ray.__version__)"` prints at least `0.6.3`. Also, try `which ray` and look in the same directory as that executable and see if there is an `rllib` executable.

Comment: This appears to have been addressed at https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ray-dev/FMNa1K6789M/discussion.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install 'ray[rllib]'` should work. When using special characters like '[' and ']', it is safe to use an apostrophe before and after the module name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the installation of ray/rllib. It is the python installation that is not done correctly. Meaning, that not all library paths are in the system path.
You need to add the "site packages" folder to your system path.

Take a look here to figure out how to find the path:
[How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)