# Editing a python package

Tags: python, package

The question is really simple:
I have a python package installed using pip3 and I'd like to tweak it a little to perform some computations. I've read (and it seems logical) that is very discouraged to not to edit the installed modules. Thus, how can I do this once I downloaded the whole project folder to my computer? Is there any way to, once edited this source code install it with another name? How can I avoid mixing things up? 
Thanks!

Comment: I agree it's discouraged.  That being said, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) will show you where to find the package.  You can make your edits there, save the file and make sure to delete any corresponding (or all) *.pyc files in that directory (they're cached module bytecode and if they exist will be used instead of the source you just edited).

Answer (score 2):

You can install the package from its source code, instead of PyPi.

1. Download the source code - do a `git clone <package-git-url>` of the package
2. Instead of `pip install <package>`, install with `pip install -e <package-directory-path>`
3. Change code in the source code, and it will be picked up automatically.