# pyautogui typewrite() writes to shell instead of clicked input/document

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am following [Chapter 18 of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/#calibre_link-3667). I'm on OS X.

I am trying to use `pyautogui` to click on a text input or text document and then input text.

I am entering the following into a shell (`(370, 80)` are the coordinates of my Chrome address bar):

`pyautogui.click(370,80); pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!')`

`click()` seems to not be working as expected. It will highlight text in an input when I click on the input, but even when I manually type after the click, the text shows up in the shell. See the below screenshot of the result of running the above line:

[image]

Other methods like `position`, `moveTo`, `moveRel`, and `dragTo` are working as expected.

If I run `time.sleep(5); pyautogui.typewrite('test')` and manually click on the text document or input while the thread is sleeping, the text is inputted as desired.

What might be the problem?

Comment: You might need a small delay to give the Chrome window time to come to the front and start receiving keyboard events.

Comment: @jasonharper I've tried `pyautogui.click(370,80); time.sleep(3); pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!')` and the text is still written to the shell after they 3 second delay.

Comment: Did Chrome actually come to the front during the delay?

Comment: @jasonharper It does not. The text in the address bar becomes highlighted, but the shell window remains in the front of Chrome.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but when I run a `pyautogui` command, a Python icon shows up in my dock. Right-clicking this icon pulls up a menu that says the application is not responding. However, my `pyautogui` and other Python commands continue to work fine (aside from the above issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug related to `click()` in OSX. Here is the solve:

1. Open the `__init__.py` file in the pyautogui package directory (find the location of your Python packages using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447/2433865).
2. On line 510 (in the `click()` function), change the fourth argument to `platformModule._multiClick()` from `3` to `clicks` (no quotes). So the correct invocation is `platformModule._multiClick(x, y, button, clicks)`
3. Save the edited file.

There is an [open PR](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/pull/358) to fix the issue.