# MySQL function (macro?) available to all databases?

Tags: mysql

I often find myself doing `select group_concat(COLUMN_NAME separator ', ') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='<current database>' AND TABLE_NAME='<argument>';`. I manually copy-paste this in and change `<current database>` and `<argument>` as appropriate but it'd be wonderful if I could just do `somescript(foo)` or somesuch and it would automatically fill in the current database and put `foo` in `argument`.

Comment: *"MySQL function (macro?) available to all databases?"*  By the way do you mean databases as in `CREATE DATABASE` or in other vendor RDMS?  As it is not totally clear what you mean..

Comment: As in `CREATE DATABASE`. MySQL `CREATE FUNCTION` as far as I am aware is database bound.

Comment: *"MySQL function (macro?) available to all databases?"* i wonder, you might like [common_schema](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema) which enables [QueryScript](https://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/query_script.html) to "marco" with on MySQL Servers ... But i still i might be interpreting your question wrong if i did see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and or explain your user case better..

Answer (score 0):

While the MySQL CLI apparently can't do any of this, I just discovered https://github.com/dbcli/mycli which added most of this (except the current database part) at the end of 2017 in [1.14.0](https://www.mycli.net/v1.14.0):

> Add positional parameters to favorite queries (Thanks: Scrappy Soft).

While not available in the mycli version bundled with Ubuntu 18.04 (which is what WSL ships with) it is available from `pip install mycli` and while the readme states you "might" need root, my experience was I didn't need sudo but it was unable to find the binary, I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447/308851 and ran `python -m site`, ran `find ~/.local -name mycli` and then added the resulting directory to `PATH`.

Comment: It wasn't about finding tools but what can I do if `mysql` itself is not scriptable?

Comment: Fair enough.. Did you check mine comment under the question about QueryScript?