# PyOpenSSL with ffi.from_buffer(b"") Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Cannot import or even install anything using pip after installing pyopenssl. Getting the following error

```
***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/home/srnadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 15, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 152, in <module>
    with ffi.from_buffer(b""):
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode or bytearray object***
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work

rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/

pip3 uninstall pyopenssl

easy_install pyopenssl

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me as well. (I'm running Python 3.7 on MacOS Catalina with Anaconda).

So apparently that's a problem with either `cryptography` module. Even `pip uninstall` wasn't working.

You could use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) for finding out the location of the cryptography package and delete it. Once deleted, just do `pip install --upgrade cryptography` and it will just work fine.

But in my case that wasn't working. So here's what I did:

1. Activate your env which has this problem. That could be done using `conda activate <env_name>` or `source <path_to_env>/bin/activate`.
   (If there's no env, just skip this step)
2. Next execute `where python` or just `conda info --envs` if you're using anaconda. This should give you the path to the python executable. In my case it was `~/opt/anaconda3` as the output for `conda info --envs`.
3. Next just `cd` into that directory and then remove (or move it somewhere else in case you want a backup) the `~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python/cryptography` folder. Or you could even do `find . | grep cryptography` after `cd`ing in the particular env folder to know the exact location of the package.
4. Next execute `pip install --upgrade cryptography`. In case that didn't work, you could try the same with the `pyopenssl` package.

Hope it helped.