# What directory are Python packages installed in?[MAC]

Tags: python, pycharm, installation

I downloaded pycharm and python 3.8, but everytime I try to pip install it goes to some hidden opt/ directory. When i type python --version in the terminal, it says 2.7. I suppose I need to get better with the command line but not sure what to do.

I'd GREATLY appreciate any help on this. Been browsing similar questions for hours and nothing helps.

Comment: In Python 3.8 pip is your dependency manager, so you should be able to use pip commands. See the following existing post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory.

Comment: You may have version 2.7 and 3.8 installed. Pycharm has the ability to select the version, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.

Answer (score 1):

I think Pycharm by default uses a virtual environment with new projects. Have you tried using the terminal in Pycharm itself? Also, check your installations, you may have multiple Python installations causing the issue.