# ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'ruamel-yaml' while creating docker image for azure ML ACI deployment

Tags: python, azure, docker, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

**I am trying to deploy machine learning model in azure ACI but i am getting following error while creating a docker image**

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'ruamel-yaml'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot 
accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Below is my yml file for pip dependencies

```
name: project_environment
dependencies:
# The python interpreter version.

# Currently Azure ML only supports 3.5.2 and later.


- pip:
  # Required packages for AzureML execution, history, and data preparation.
  - pandas
  - azureml-defaults
  - azureml-sdk
  - azureml-widgets
  - numpy
  - tensorflow-gpu
  - keras
  - azureml-defaults
  - torch==1.4.0
  - scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
```

and if i use conda instead of pip then i am getting following error

```
Step 11/13 : RUN CONDA_ROOT_DIR=$(conda info --root) && if [ -n 
"$AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH" ]; then conda env update -p 
"$AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH" -f '/var/azureml-app/binary_2.yml'; else 
conda env update -n base -f '/var/azureml-app/binary_2.yml'; fi && conda 
clean -aqy && rm -rf /root/.cache/pip && rm -rf "$CONDA_ROOT_DIR/pkgs" && 
find "$CONDA_ROOT_DIR" -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} +
---> Running in 9e6eb7278bfc  
[91mUnable to install package for Conda.

Please double check and ensure you dependencies file has
the correct spelling.  You might also try installing the
conda-env-Conda package to see if provides the required
installer. 
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c CONDA_ROOT_DIR=$(conda info --root) && if [ -n 
"$AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH" ]; then conda env update -p 
"$AZUREML_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT_PATH" -f '/var/azureml-app/binary_2.yml'; else 
 conda env update -n base -f '/var/azureml-app/binary_2.yml'; fi && conda 
clean 
-aqy && rm -rf /root/.cache/pip && rm -rf "$CONDA_ROOT_DIR/pkgs" && find 
"$CONDA_ROOT_DIR" -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} +' returned a 
non- 
 zero code: 255
 2020/08/12 19:36:09 Container failed during run: acb_step_0. No retries 
 remaining.
 failed to run step ID: acb_step_0: exit status 255
```

**Can anyone please help me **

Comment: You seem to have omitted the config file that produced the error. We can't read your mind.

Comment: which config file can you just give me example

Comment: you said you used conda to generate the error, but your config file shows only pip. presumably the config file that used conda was different than what you have in the question. the error suggests you might have spelled a package wrong. did you double check them?

Comment: i said i used conda so i have made changes in my actual file not here in question .. and yes i have given the right name .. i have checked again .."Conda

Comment: i'm saying if you've tried two different things you should show us both of those things

Comment: I am having the same issue? Can you tell me how you were able to fix this

Answer (score 18):

This is a problem ever since pip version 10 ([relevant discussion on the pip repo](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247)). That thread details a few solutions:

[Manually delete](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247#issuecomment-381550610) the files from `site-packages`. In my case, to delete `ruamel.yaml` the command was `rm -rf /path/to/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel*`

[You can also](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247#issuecomment-410910018) downgrade pip to version <10, reinstall ruamel with the `--disable-pip-version-check` option, then reverse the downgrade with `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Update: here's a 1-liner that deletes the ruamel packages:

`rm -rf $(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())")/ruamel*`

Breaking that down: everything in the $(...) is a one-liner to get your global site-packages dir ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122340/4212158)). The `rm -rf` deletes the ruamel package directories recursively. The `/ruamel*` suffix targets the ruamel package.

I've encountered this same issue with other packages (`boto`, `gmpy2`, `pycosat`) and the solution was the same, except to replace the suffix.

Answer (score 5):

maybe use "pip install --ignore-installed [package]"

Answer (score 0):

I was using a *`miniconda3`* installation and had the same problem.
Following crypdick's answer, I had to do the following using conda in Powershell:

```sh
# List outdated packages
pip list -o

# Try to update with:
pip install -U ruamel-yaml
# get error-1
...

# try to uninstall with conda: 
conda update ruamel-yaml

# get error-2
# PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
#   prefix: C:\Users\<user>\miniconda3
#   package name: ruamel-yaml

# Remove index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.
conda clean -a -vv
conda deactivate

# Remove any files related to "ruamel-yaml":
# WARNING: Recursive removal, so don't fuck this up!
cd $env:CONDA_PREFIX
gci -r -fi "ruamel*" | ForEach-Object { rm -Recurse -Force $_.FullName }

# From now on, "conda" will not work until we re-install:
# Make sure your pip version & path is correct.
pip -V 
pip install ruamel_yaml
```

Now conda works again!

Comment: @cidermole Please don't change source code without informing us! You just changed the environment variable to something I didn't have/use at the time. If you want to provide a solution that works for you, then post your own answer.