# Can't install Azure packages with pip: ruamel.yaml error

Tags: azure, gcc, pip, ruamel.yaml

I'm having trouble installing the following packages in a new python 3.9.7 virtual environment on Arch Linux.

**My requirements.txt file:**

```
joblib
python-dotenv
azure-cli==2.29.2
azureml-core
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. `python3 -m venv venv`
2. `source venv/bin/activate`
3. `pip install -U pip`
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Here's the relevant part of the output of the last command, it errors when trying to install `ruamel.yaml`:

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for ruamel.yaml, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pycparser, urllib3, idna, chardet, cffi, certifi, six, requests, PyJWT, oauthlib, cryptography, requests-oauthlib, python-dateutil, isodate, azure-nspkg, wrapt, tabulate, pyyaml, PySocks, pyopenssl, PyNaCl, pygments, portalocker, msrest, msal, MarkupSafe, jmespath, colorama, bcrypt, azure-mgmt-nspkg, azure-core, argcomplete, applicationinsights, adal, websocket-client, vsts, pyparsing, pyasn1, psutil, pkginfo, pathlib2, paramiko, msrestazure, msal-extensions, knack, jinja2, jeepney, invoke, humanfriendly, deprecated, backports.weakref, azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg, azure-mgmt-core, azure-common, azure-cli-telemetry, xmltodict, sshtunnel, semver, SecretStorage, scp, ruamel.yaml, pytz, PyGithub, pathspec, packaging, ndg-httpsclient, jsonpickle, jsondiff, javaproperties, fabric, docker, distro, contextlib2, backports.tempfile, azure-synapse-spark, azure-synapse-managedprivateendpoints, azure-synapse-artifacts, azure-synapse-accesscontrol, azure-storage-common, azure-multiapi-storage, azure-mgmt-web, azure-mgmt-trafficmanager, azure-mgmt-synapse, azure-mgmt-storage, azure-mgmt-sqlvirtualmachine, azure-mgmt-sql, azure-mgmt-signalr, azure-mgmt-servicefabricmanagedclusters, azure-mgmt-servicefabric, azure-mgmt-servicebus, azure-mgmt-security, azure-mgmt-search, azure-mgmt-resource, azure-mgmt-reservations, azure-mgmt-relay, azure-mgmt-redis, azure-mgmt-redhatopenshift, azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup, azure-mgmt-recoveryservices, azure-mgmt-rdbms, azure-mgmt-privatedns, azure-mgmt-policyinsights, azure-mgmt-network, azure-mgmt-netapp, azure-mgmt-msi, azure-mgmt-monitor, azure-mgmt-media, azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering, azure-mgmt-maps, azure-mgmt-managementgroups, azure-mgmt-managedservices, azure-mgmt-loganalytics, azure-mgmt-kusto, azure-mgmt-keyvault, azure-mgmt-iothubprovisioningservices, azure-mgmt-iothub, azure-mgmt-iotcentral, azure-mgmt-imagebuilder, azure-mgmt-hdinsight, azure-mgmt-extendedlocation, azure-mgmt-eventhub, azure-mgmt-eventgrid, azure-mgmt-dns, azure-mgmt-devtestlabs, azure-mgmt-deploymentmanager, azure-mgmt-datamigration, azure-mgmt-datalake-store, azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics, azure-mgmt-databoxedge, azure-mgmt-cosmosdb, azure-mgmt-containerservice, azure-mgmt-containerregistry, azure-mgmt-containerinstance, azure-mgmt-consumption, azure-mgmt-compute, azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices, azure-mgmt-cdn, azure-mgmt-botservice, azure-mgmt-billing, azure-mgmt-batchai, azure-mgmt-batch, azure-mgmt-authorization, azure-mgmt-applicationinsights, azure-mgmt-appconfiguration, azure-mgmt-apimanagement, azure-mgmt-advisor, azure-loganalytics, azure-keyvault-keys, azure-keyvault-administration, azure-keyvault, azure-identity, azure-graphrbac, azure-functions-devops-build, azure-datalake-store, azure-cosmos, azure-cli-core, azure-batch, azure-appconfiguration, antlr4-python3-runtime, python-dotenv, joblib, azureml-core, azure-cli
    Running setup.py install for ruamel.yaml: started
    Running setup.py install for ruamel.yaml: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/zjeffer/Documents/school/howest-mct/semester5/mlops/labo/project/mlops-project/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ouy4o2zq/ruamel-yaml_763ae0866f7e4425a0965a00130752b0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ouy4o2zq/ruamel-yaml_763ae0866f7e4425a0965a00130752b0/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8y_97owt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/zjeffer/Documents/school/howest-mct/semester5/mlops/labo/project/mlops-project/venv/include/site/python3.9/ruamel.yaml
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ouy4o2zq/ruamel-yaml_763ae0866f7e4425a0965a00130752b0/
    Complete output (649 lines):
    sys.argv ['/tmp/pip-install-ouy4o2zq/ruamel-yaml_763ae0866f7e4425a0965a00130752b0/setup.py', 'install', '--record', '/tmp/pip-record-8y_97owt/install-record.txt', '--single-version-externally-managed', '--compile', '--install-headers', '/home/zjeffer/Documents/school/howest-mct/semester5/mlops/labo/project/mlops-project/venv/include/site/python3.9/ruamel.yaml']
    test compiling test_ruamel_yaml
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel
    copying .ruamel/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./main.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./tokens.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./scalarfloat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./scanner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./comments.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./loader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./serializer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./resolver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./nodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./dumper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./configobjwalker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./timestamp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./reader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./cyaml.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./representer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./events.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./scalarbool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./composer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./scalarint.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./emitter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./anchor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./constructor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./scalarstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    copying ./LICENSE -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ruamel/yaml
    running build_ext
    building '_ruamel_yaml' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/ext
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fno-semantic-interposition -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fPIC -I/home/zjeffer/Documents/school/howest-mct/semester5/mlops/labo/project/mlops-project/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c ext/_ruamel_yaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/ext/_ruamel_yaml.o
    In file included from ext/_ruamel_yaml.c:523:
    ext/_ruamel_yaml.h:10: warning: "PyString_CheckExact" redefined

<a whole bunch of compiling errors & warnings>
```

The full log file can be found [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zjeffer/9adf4e9db0c908b103dbc5ca6a886664/raw/a5689c0e04646fc96724321d1e7aa1fcef114fdd/log.txt)

Note the line `Using legacy 'setup.py install' for ruamel.yaml, since package 'wheel' is not installed.`. If I first install the `wheel` package, the same error appears when installing the packages.

Installing `ruamel.yaml` manually works fine, but the azure packages still can't be installed.

**EDIT:** Installing every package one by one installs everything without errors. Why?

Changing step 3 to `pip install -U pip wheel ruamel.yaml` doesn't change anything.

Comment: When you install every package one by one, do you install azure-cli using `pip install azure-cli==2.29.2` ?

Comment: yes (commentshaveminimumcharacterlimit)

Comment: I tried on arch with python3.9 and 3.7 and with and without requirements.txt. It is unclear to me why when not using the requirements.txt `ruamel.yaml` is not installed at all, and why with the requirements.txt it is installed twice (see updated answer). But there are version conflicts within azure packages, so maybe that is the cause.

Comment: Just for tracking. Here is a related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383400/error-cannot-uninstall-ruamel-yaml-while-creating-docker-image-for-azure-ml-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ruamel.yaml` [documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) states that it should be installed using:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

so using the legacy `[python] setup.py install` should not be used.

Your full log indicates that it is tried to install two versions of ruamel.yaml:

```
Collecting ruamel.yaml<=0.17.16,>=0.17.10
Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.17.16-py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
```

and

```
Collecting ruamel.yaml<=0.15.89,>=0.15.35
Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.15.89.tar.gz (306 kB)
```

Apart from a potential problem with two versions being installed, the second one will not succeed as the 0.15 ruamel.yaml series (the last one uploaded to PyPI in July 2019) doesn't support Python 3.9 first released in Oct 2020.

So when you install each package step by step, you get the latest version or ruamel.yaml. Why that step by step installation doesn't at with some package tries to install `ruamel.yaml==0.15.89` as a dependency is unclear.

When I install the four packages listed in your `requirements.txt`, then `ruamel.yaml` doesn't get installed but `pipdeptree`  indicates that `azureml-core==1.36.0.post2` has possible conflicting dependencies.

When I use your `requirements.txt` I get the same error.

When I use your `requirements.txt` in a Python 3.7 `venv` (so that the old ruamel.yaml wheel can be installed) installation works. From that you can see that the package `azureml-core==1.14.0` is installed instead of the `azureml-core==1.36.0.post2`

Comment: "but since you snipped the interesting part of the ouput" -> I included the full log under the snippet.

Comment: Sorry missed that, updated my answer.

Comment: Using Python 3.7 worked for me.