# Python import works in app but not in command prompt or script

Tags: python, import, interpreter

Python App Pic:
[image: PythonAppPic]

Command Prompt Pic:
[image: CommandPromptPic]

They both clearly show their versions match so I'm at a loss for what to do here.

Comment: BTW, here is the shebang from the script I mentioned: #!/usr/bin/env python3

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out where Python app is picking up the module cv2:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__file__)
```

Then you can see if your user has the right access to the directory.

You can always install the missing module in the Command Prompt to your local user site-packages by:

```
pip3 install --user <module name>
```

You can also run on the command prompt:

```
python -m site
```

This will show you the directories Python is looking in for module.

(Taken from [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory))