# Python imports that work both when using a file as a module and when called directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I was reading today about [absolute and relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) in Python, and I was wondering if there is a pythonic way of making an import work when the script that contains the import is used as a module and when it is called directly. As an example:

```
└── project
      ├── main.py
      └── package
             ├── submoduleA.py
             └── submoduleB.py
```

*main.py*

```
from package.submoduleA import submoduleAfunction
submoduleAfunction()
```

*submoduleB.py*

```
def submoduleBfunction():
    print('Hi from submoduleBfunction')
```

*submoduleA.py*

```
# Absolute import, works when called directly: python3 package/submoduleA.py 
from submoduleB import submoduleBfunction 

# Relative import, works when imported as module: python3 main.py
# from .submoduleB import submoduleBfunction 

def submoduleAfunction():
    submoduleBfunction()
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    submoduleAfunction()
```

As you see, I have there both absolute and relative imports. Each of them works in a specific situation. But is there a pythonic way of making it work for both cases? So far I've done the trick messing with `sys.path`, but I'm not sure that this will work in every situation (i.e. called from interpreter or in different OS's) or even if this goes against any recommendations.

```
import sys
import pathlib
sys.path.append(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()))
```

Comment: At work we have a root folder on the path, and everything is in subdirectories inside it, so everything imports from the top level. For example, if you run `company/scripts/something.py`, then that might have `from company.scripts.something_else import x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Absolute import, works when called directly: python3 package/submoduleA.py 
from submoduleB import submoduleBfunction
```

Since `submoduleA` is the "sibling" of `submoduleB`, this is actually an implicit relative import.  The [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says of them:

> Implicit relative imports should never be used and have been removed in Python 3.

The only reason it even works when running `python3 package/submoduleA.py` as a script is that Python prepends the directory of the script to `sys.path`.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

That is, the directory `/path/to/package` gets injected to `sys.path`, allowing `submoduleB` to be imported directly.

Implicit relative imports should never be used, so what should you use instead? It doesn't matter, you can use the correct form of the absolute import:

```
from package.submoduleB import submoduleBfunction
```

or a relative import:

```
from .submoduleB import submoduleBfunction
```

Either is fine as long as `package` has been installed into the environment (installing the package is what will put the code into [site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory/52638888), which is on `sys.path`).

If you absolute must run `package/submoduleA.py` directly as a script, which is [considered an anti-pattern](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html), then you will need to use the absolute import version. Relative imports [do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) in this case. You would need to use instead `python3 -m package.submoduleA` in order for the relative-import version to work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer:

- Your mileage may vary and I realize that my answer does not fully answer the question (using **relative** imports).  Mea maxima culpa (my bad).
- In my defense:  googling *python avoid relative imports* returns 540k hits.

I usually avoid relative imports because they seem to have too many special cases on just this type of things and I am a huge fan of running python files directly as scripts when appropriate.

For example, my `constants.py` file can be run as a script - it will `breakpoint()` and I can inspect its contents, a good deal of which come from environment variables.

Assuming that the *parent* directory for `project` is in your Python path, I would just use `from project.package.submoduleA import submoduleAfunction`.  That works in all cases.

(One *possible* additional benefit I found with explicit imports is when I wanted to rename my top-level package (`myproject` to `myproject2`).  Having everything explicit allowed me to quickly `sed` the changes.  Note Wim's remarks in the comments below)

Comment: The last point doesn't really make sense to me. If you use relative imports, then there is no need to replace import statements at all during a rename (only changing the top-level package name is needed), so how is that is an "additional benefit" of absolute imports?

Comment: Don't really recall except that, when I did it, it did seem that being very explicit and importing from the top down made it easier.  I did reorganize my code by using `pip install -E ` on the equivalent of the OP's parent dir however, so that might have been part of it.

Comment: Oh, and one reason from my *anti-patterning* is that I write celery tasks that run massive batches.  Those are fully exercised and debugged from the command line, not via celery launches.  Even end users can also run them from the CLI.  Celery is very much relegated to being a barebones invocation method but it does need to import those batches.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is to just enclose the absolute import in a `try` block and catch an `ImportException`. In case of an exception, you are presumably using it as a module so then do a relative import.

```
try:
    ​from submoduleB import submoduleBfunction 
except ImportException:
    from .submoduleB import submoduleBfunction
```

Comment: This is not safe, in the general case `mod` and `.mod` may refer to entirely different packages.