# Distributing or Installing the C++ Python Extension Pyd file

Tags: python, c++, windows, pybind11

I am using PyBind11 to create a C++ Extension for Python. I am using visual studio and I am able to successfully create the pyd file.

I used the Visual Studio project properties and build using MSBuild to create the pyd file. Now I want to distribute this as a Python package. Like user can do `Pip install CppExtension`.

All the solution says to use setup.py to install the pyd file to any python environment. But the setup.py will compile the cpp files and create a pyd file and then install it.

But I already have a compiled pyd. Is there any way to directly install the pyd file into the user environment without compiling the CPP files.

I am looking for a Windows Solution.

Workaround: By adding the folder path to PYTHONPATH Environment variable I am able to import and use in other Python project. But I think this is more for a development environment.

Comment: You could put your pyd file to a location that is on the `PYTHONPATH` ? This is easy to automate, for instance if you make an installer.

Comment: The PYTHONPATH is not present in the environment variable to begin with, I need to explicitly create them. Is that a valid approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you don't have a python installed?

Comment: I have it installed, the PYTHONPATH variable in windows is not created by default. I need to add it manually.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to create `PYTHONPATH`, you could put the `pyd` file to a default location (which you can get [running some python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447/3283333))  but depending on how you get Python (conda, virtualenv, ...) the default does not work