# How do Python Virtual Environment Symlinks Work?

Tags: python, virtualenv

If I create a Python virtual environment like so:

```
$ python3 -m venv my_venv
```

... and then look at the Python binary in the bin directory like so:

```
$ ls -l my_env/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 fred fred  7 Sep 12 15:57 my_env/bin/python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 fred fred 16 Sep 12 15:57 my_env/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
```

I see that the `python` is symlinked to the main global `python`. Therefore, what mechanism ensures that the Python packages we install after activating the virtual environment, that the packages are installed to `site-packages`?

Comment: The short answer is that the `site` module (created on startup) is responsible for constructing the `site-packages` directory.

Comment: I guess it should be explained in  ["_PEP 405 – Python Virtual Environments_" Specification](https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/#specification) -- "_If a `pyvenv.cfg` file is found either adjacent to the Python executable or one directory above it (if the executable is a symlink, it is not dereferenced), this file is scanned for lines of the form `key = value`. If a `home` key is found, this signifies that the Python binary belongs to a virtual environment, and the value of the `home` key is the directory containing the Python executable used to create this virtual environment._"

Answer (score 1):

I was interested so I did a little searching and performed a couple experiments. A reference:
[How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)

I created a virtual environment my_venv in /tmp and did *not* activate it. On Linux activating a virtual environment (`my_venv/bin/activate`) adds the virtual environment's `bin` directory to the path; I found I could simulate that by using the full path; i.e., executing `./my_venv/bin/python` and `./my_venv/bin/pip` directly. Results of such experimentation:

```
> ################### system executables
> python3 -m site       # system's python
sys.path = [
    <current directory>
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
> pip3 show <a package>    # system's pip
...
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
...
> pip3 show <package installed in the venv>
WARNING: Package(s) not found

> ################### venv executables
> /tmp/my_venv/bin/python3 -m site
sys.path = [
    <current directory>
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/tmp/my_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
]
> /tmp/my_venv/bin/pip3 show <package installed in the venv>
...
Location: /tmp/my_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
...
> /tmp/my_venv/bin/pip3 show <package installed on the system>
WARNING: Package(s) not found
```

I took a peek at the activation script, `/tmp/my_venv/bin/activate`. It set a couple environment variables, notably one named `VIRTUAL_ENV`. I set this environment variable to the path to my virtual environment, as it would have been set if I'd activated the virtual environment. Then I checked paths using the system's `python -m site` and `pip show <package>`, and got the same responses I'd gotten without the environment variable set. From this information I concluded that python and pip probably don't pay attention to the environment variable.

I then symlinked the system's `python3` and `pip3` executables to a local directory, and got the same responses from commands using these (`./python3` and `./pip3`) that I'd gotten from the system executables.

I then created the following directory structure:

```
bin/python3    # symlink to system python3
bin/pip3       # symlink to system pip3
lib/python3.10/site-packages/
```

These still gave me the system paths. However, as soon as I copied the file `pyvenv.cfg` from a virtual environment into my directory structure, it started to use my local paths!

*Note: I copied pyvenv.cfg straight from the real virtual environment without changing it. That file contained the line "home = /usr/bin/".*

I concluded that in order to determine the path to site-packages, Python uses the path of the executed file by preference (even if that's a symlink), and knows to look for a virtual environment configuration file one directory up from the executable. If the path is a symlink and doesn't yield a valid path, looks like it is able to back to the path of the actual executed file.

(this agrees with [sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc)'s summary of [PEP 405 – Python Virtual Environments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/#specification), written while I was fooling around)

This is deductive, of course. The source code would also provide the definitive answer.