# Where do python packages get installed in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

I logged into `Azure` portal, opened `cli/powershell` and executed `pip install` to download some `python packages`. Where do these packages get installed?

I am aware that I need a `storage` account when using `cli`. `Azure` prompted and created a `resource group` and `storage account` when I used `cli/shell` for the first time.

After installing the packages, I went to the `storage browser` of the `storage account` but I don't see any files anywhere.

Comment: No idea about Azure specifically, but can you not find `purelib` as described in [How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)? Additionally, if you already have a package installed, `python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)'` should tell you exactly where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the same as you mentioned and after downloading I used `pip show`  and I can find the location of installed package.

[image]

The packages will not be stored in your mounted Azure Storage Account but it stored in Azure Cloud Shell Environment which is managed internally by Azure Cloud Shell.

If you want to manage the packages you can do that in the cloud shell terminal itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific when you post questions. What you are talking about is The Azure Cloud Shell (not "Azure" as a general thing). Cloud Shell uses a storage account to persist certain settings in a storage account. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage).