# Msys2: Python 2.7 and Python 3.8 side by side, how to load correct site.py

Tags: python, msys2

I have portable msys2 under Windows.
It works great.

I have both python 2.7 and python 3.8 installed.
If I load python 3.8 it works fine.

```
$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 16 2020, 15:31:48)
[GCC 9.3.0] on msys
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Reading /home/user/.pythonrc
readline is in /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-38-i386-msys.dll
>>>
```

But I can't load python2

```
$ python2
  File "/c/Users/user1/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 178
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I setup msys2 correctly for both versions?
Where is the dir that contains `site.py` specified?

Comment: Remove brace bracket at the end.

Comment: @toyotaSupra - Which brace bracket?

Comment: line 178
    file=sys.stderr)

Comment: @toyotaSupra - I don't think that is appropriate, for very many reasons: 1) it will break syntax, 2) it is not a file that a user (e.g., me) generates or modifies, with a few exceptions, 3) etc., etc.
If you could justify your suggestion, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Helped by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447/2707864), I realized I need to use

```
export PYTHONPATH=/c/Users/user1/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python2.7:/c/Users/user1/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

The default was with 3.8.
I setup respective aliases (I have a suitable `export` for `MINGW_HOME`)

```
alias python2="export PYTHONPATH=${MINGW_HOME}/lib/python2.7:${MINGW_HOME}/lib/python2.7/site-packages; /usr/bin/python2"
alias python3="export PYTHONPATH=${MINGW_HOME}/lib/python3.8:${MINGW_HOME}/lib/python3.8/site-packages; /usr/bin/python3"
```